# How to disable built-in code box when using Syntaxhighlighter3?

Tags: dokuwiki, syntaxhighlighter

[image]

I'm using Dokuwiki and want to get rid built-in code box (boxes with grey outline) when using Syntaxhighlighter3.

Appreciate if anyone know how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Add these lines to the css file (in your case **shCore.css**)

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 !important;
```

The file **sxh3\styles\shCore.css** ( when the above line is inserted at line 28 ) would like as follows:

```
.syntaxhighlighter table tbody,
.syntaxhighlighter table thead,
.syntaxhighlighter table caption,
.syntaxhighlighter textarea {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 0 !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 0 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 !important; /* <-- this line */
  background: none !important;
  border: 0 !important;
  bottom: auto !important;
  float: none !important;
  height: auto !important;
```